# Multiple choices are not saving in Dango admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am building a BlogApp and I am storing user's multiple interest in a `CharField`. I have used `multiple select field` in html. Choices are showing fine BUT when i try to save multiple values at a time then only one is adding.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

template.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="full_name">
            <label for="interests">Choose Interests:</label>
            <select name="interests" id="interests" multiple>
                <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
                <option value="piano">Piano</option>
                <option value="eating">Eating</option>
            </select>
            <div class = "col text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Name" />
            </div>

        </div>
    <form>
</div>
```

When i try to select more than one interest and check admin then it is showing only one interest.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Please [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your model schema first (Storing multiple values in one column is bad schema design). After that look into using [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: Can you share the function you are calling onclick? Can you try changing the field from CharField to OneToManyField?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, How can i make `model schema`  ?

Comment: @JonathSujan, I can't  use `ForeignKey` Because its just a field and i want to add with Profile. I am not using any kind of `onclick` event

Comment: Since it's a multiple select, you want the name to end with [] (so that it's posted as an array).